# Suppose that $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $W$ is a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

a) Prove that there exists a subspace $W'$ and a function $T : V\to V$ such that $T$ is a projection on $W$ along $W'$.

b) Give an example of a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ such that there are two projections on $W$ along two (distinct) subspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is $n$ dimensional for some $n \in \{2, 3, \dots\}$, and suppose $W$ is $m$-dimensional for some $m \in \{1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$.

a) Let $w=(w_1, \dots, w_m)$ be some ordered basis for $W$. Extend $w$ to an ordered basis $v=(w_1, \dots, w_m, w_{m+1}, \dots, w_n)$ for $V$. Define $W'$ to be the span of $\{w_{m+1}, \dots, w_n\}$. For every $x \in V$, consider the unique representation of $x$ as a linear combination of the members of the basis $v$: $x = a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n$. Define $T(x) := a_1w_1 + \cdots + a_mw_m$.

b) Let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $W$ be the $y$-axis. Consider the projection of $x := (1,1)$ when $W' = \mathrm{span}\{(1,0)\}$, and when $W' = \mathrm{span}\{(1,1)\}$. In the first case, the projection is $(0,1)$, whereas in the second case it is $(0,0)$.